# Ant build from Android-generated build file fails - how to fix?

Tags: android, memory, ant, build

Building our Android app from Ant fails with this error:

```
    [apply] 
    [apply] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
    [apply] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    [apply]     at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:209)
    [apply]     at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:86)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.compress(Dominators.java:96)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.eval(Dominators.java:132)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.Dominators.run(Dominators.java:213)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.DomFront.run(DomFront.java:84)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.placePhiFunctions(SsaConverter.java:265)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:51)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:100)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:74)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:269)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:131)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:85)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:297)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:276)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:228)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:245)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:120)
    [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:87)

BUILD FAILED
```

Ive tried giving Ant more memory by setting ANT_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m". (This build machine has 1Gb RAM).

Do I just need more memory or is there anything else I can try?

Comment: How many classes and resources are there in your project? I have never seen this error.

Comment: Not many at all (though we are using JNI to load a static C lib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved our build to a new Hudson install on a Linux box. Problem went away.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, and this particular solution is not a problem.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Found this link that helps: http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/1e0a66a5ab115168

The solution seems to be to edit your dx or dx.bat shell script (depending on your platform) and uncomment the line that sets the heap size.

For example,

```
vi $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/*/tools/dx
```

will let you edit each of your dx files on a mac (and possibly linux).

Then uncomment the `javaOpts` line that says something like the following:

```
# If you want DX to have more memory when executing, uncomment the following
# line and adjust the value accordingly. Use "java -X" for a list of options
# you can pass here.
# 
# javaOpts="-Xmx256M"
```

This isn't an ideal solution obviously, since your changes will get clobbered every time you update your platform SDKs.  But it did do the trick for me.

Comment: There is no such folder **/tools/dx** anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `apply` task's `spawn` attribute to `true`, so that each execution is spawned as its own process. You didn't include the portion of your build.xml where you use the `apply` task, but it will look something like this:

```
<apply spawn="true" executable="command">
  <fileset dir="."/>
</apply>
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Im using the Android-generated build.xml so most of the config is pulled in from android_rules.xml and my build file is mostly empty.

Comment: same problem here.  Any other solutions besides moving to another dev box?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass heap arguments to dex via ant.

```
<apply executable="${dx}" failonerror="true" parallel="true">
            <arg value="-JXmx4096M" />
            <arg value="--dex" />
            <arg value="--multi-dex" />
```

-JXmx4096M will be parsed and set as the heap size of dex process. see shell script dex.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by editing D:\java\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat (Window Environment)

```
set defaultXmx=-Xmx3072M
set defaultXss=-Xss512m
```